# Web browsers -is there a way to disable reload on a per site basis?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, safari, web

Driving me nuts - I love using rich and feature-full webapps, but I hate what happens when I accidentally reload the page. And since I'm all about the keyboard shortcuts, it is just too easy for me to slip and accidentally hit command + R. And bam, my tinychat window puts me back to where I started. I have to log in again, select my cam, my mic, etc. Super annoying.

Obviously due to the restrictions of Flash and the web in general this a tough problem for tinychat to solve - but can the browser help? What I'm envisioning is maybe a list of sites that I never want to refresh - I'd put in the URLs for all of my webapps that take several steps to restore state. Then, next time I accidentally reload, it's ignored. In case I did want to reload a page in a specific instance, there would be a manual override. Anything out there like this?

I use Safari and while I'm not eager to switch to Firefox, it'd be worth noting here if there are extensions that solve this problem.

Comment: +1 for leading me to learn about browser shortcuts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a "site specific browser" (SSB), using Fluid.app, that is dedicated to tinychat.

More on Fluid.app here: http://fluidapp.com. Fluid even uses Webkit for rendering, so pages should look exactly the same as Safari.

Once you've created the SSB you can hide the browser toolbar, so you don't *see* the Refresh icon.

Additionally, because it's a separate application from Safari, you should be able to override the Command-R refresh shortcut in your Mac's System Prefs while keeping it in place in Safari for every other website.

To do that, go to System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts. Just create a new shortcut for Command-R that does something innocuous, like, maybe "Window > Bring All To Front".

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible using javascript. You can have a webpage prompt you when changing page (including refreshing, or closing the tab,) usually to warn you that you might lose data if you continue.

It even does it here! Try typing something as an answer and then click refresh.

Using Greasemonkey, one could very easily make a configured list of websites use this prompt all the time.

To directly answer your question though: No browsers support the feature you are asking for directly. HOWEVER, there is a Firefox extension that I strongly recommend that will do exactly what you want:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122

Using TabMixPlus, you can right click on any tab and "lock" it. That will prevent it from being reloaded or the page changing at all. If you click a link in a locked tab, it will be forced to open in a new tab.

Comment: Link is dead and the addon is not currently supported.